# Introducir texto en un archivo en determinada columna Shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Tengo que modificar la columna 5 de un archivo de texto separado con `:` (dos puntos). Por el texto que introduzca el usuario, ya corté la columna 5 con `cut -f5 -d:`, pero no sé cómo introducir el texto en ese espacio vació que queda.

El texto que introduce el usuario está almacenado en una variable.

Answer (score 1):

Usa `awk`:

```
awk -v nuevo_valor="NOCHE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{$5=nuevo_valor}1' archivo
```

¿Cómo funciona esto?

- `-v nuevo_valor="NOCHE"`
  proporciona al script el valor con el que sustituir la columna.
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}`
  define el separador de campos; en este caso, dos puntos.
- `{$5=nuevo_valor}`
  asigna al 5º campo el valor dado con la variable `nuevo_valor`.
- `1` 
  evalúa como True (cierto) por lo que ejecuta el comando predeterminado de `awk`: `{print $0}`; esto es, escribir el registro actual.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ cat archivo
hola:como:estas:esta:mañana:yo:bien
$ awk -v nuevo_valor="NOCHE" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{$5=nuevo_valor}1' archivo
hola:como:estas:esta:NOCHE:yo:bien
```